# How can I access the result from a previous function in a currying function?

Tags: javascript, currying, arrow-functions

I have to write a currying function that takes a function, executes another function, then executes a second function by taking the last argument as the value to calculate with.

**What I am struggling with: How can I access the first function and the value at the end at the same time?**

So far I can access the first function by writing a function in the function syntax and accessing the this.

```
Function.prototype.foo = function(x) {
  // can't make currying functions by using functions keyword
  console.log(this, x);
};

(() => 10).foo(1);
```

When I write a currying function I can access the second (x) and third (y) function.

```
Function.prototype.bar = x => y => {
  // but also can't access this like in function syntax
  console.log(x, y);
}

// how would I access 10 in bar?
(() => 10).bar(1)(2);
```

The final Function would look something like that:

```
someFunc.then(someSecondFunc).then(someThirdFunc)(100)
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it solves your problem, but you can make currying functions with the function keyword:

```
Function.prototype.bar = function(x) {
    return function(y) {
        console.log(x, y)
    }
}
```

I wasn’t able to actually able to validate if this works:

```
(function() {return 10}).bar(1)(2)
```

In any case, ˋthisˋ would be the function, not the return value (10), since the function is not called.

Comment: I didn't know that I can make currying functions without arrow functions. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

By using currying functions and the function keyword, my answer looks like this:

```
Function.prototype.then = function(secondFct) {
  const firstFct = this;
  return function(value) {
    return firstFct(secondFct(value));
  }
}
```

Many thanks to [buboh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6070191/buboh) for the help.